# How to check if named view exists in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am implementing a user role based dashboard where route view will be rendered upon role.

root view: (name is changed on user role)

```html
<template v-if="user">
    <router-view :name="user.type"></router-view>
</template>
<template v-else>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

and my route:

```js
{
      path: '/recordings',
      name: 'Recording',
      components: { default: NotFoud, shows: Recording },
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        title: 'Recording'
      },
      children: [],
    },
```

my concern is, for 'admin' role there is no component defined for `/recording` route and i want to show some default message if admin user trying to go to `recording`

how to check if there any named view component named `admin` for `recording` route exists and if not then push user to `default` view

Answer (score -1):

I solve the problem of change dashboard for different role user, using the same route, but changing the component to load.

Assuming you have AdminDashboard for admin role and ClientDashboard  for clients.

In my case, when the user is logged, store the role with Vuex

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard-container">
    <component :is="currentRole" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

import AdminDashboard from '@/views/dashboard/adminDashboard';
import ClientDashboard from '@/views/dashboard/clientDashboard';

export default {
  name: 'Dashboard',
  components: { AdminDashboard , ClientDashboard },
  data() {
    return {
      currentRole: 'AdminDashboard ',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'role',
    ]),
  },
  created() {
    if (this.role==='client'){
      this.currentRole = 'ClientDashboard';
    }
  },
};
</script>
```